# TableLayoutPanel change scrollbars (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbars, tablelayoutpanel

I do have a TableLayoutPanel with AutoScroll=true. Works fine: But is there any chance to change the style of the scrollbars. I'd like to have smaller scrollbars.

Any ideas - Regards HW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default controls are going to use the default window style scroll bars.  You would have to derive a custom class, then render it all on your own to change.

Comment: This was also my best guess, however - sometimes there are easy solutions I do not see. Thanks for helping me on this.